# Wrong result from select

Tags: sql, select

When I select something from the database like this it give me a wrong result:

```
SELECT *
FROM Werkwoord_spelling
WHERE tijd = 'tt'
AND soort = 'sw'
AND vorm = 'i'
OR vorm = 'j'
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 20
```

Here some rows from the result:

```
 527  Afgelopen zomer leefde jij al twaalf jaar. vt zw j leven leefde
 1346 Stop je nog met kletsen? tt zw j stoppen Stop
```

You can see that I have an *'vt'* in row 527, but I only ask for rows with *'tt'* as in row 1346.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Could you please mark either of the answers below as accepted to bring closure to your question? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add parenthesis for your logical group.
i think the query is this

```
SELECT *
FROM Werkwoord_spelling
WHERE tijd = 'tt'
AND soort = 'sw'
AND (vorm = 'i'OR vorm = 'j')
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: ok, check one of this answers, like the answer of your question

Answer (score 1):

That is because you have an `or` in your where.
Change to:

```
SELECT * FROM Werkwoord_spelling WHERE tijd = 'tt' AND soort = 'sw' AND (vorm = 'i' OR vorm= 'j' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 20)
```

and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Note that AND has precedence over OR, so your WHERE condition equivalents to:

```
WHERE (tijd = 'tt' AND soort = 'sw' AND vorm = 'i') OR vorm = 'j'
```

I guess it has to be:

```
WHERE tijd = 'tt' AND soort = 'sw' AND (vorm = 'i' OR vorm = 'j')
```

So use brackets.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite your query using a couple parenthesis like so:

```
SELECT * FROM Werkwoord_spelling 
WHERE tijd = 'tt' AND soort = 'sw' AND vorm in ('i', 'j') 
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 20
```

This way, you are telling the database to give you records if all of the conditions are met:

- tijd is tt
- soort is sw
- vorm is either i or j

In your query, the `OR`s position was an issue. The database was retrieving records that matched all of the conditions below

- tijd is tt
- soort is sw
- vorm is either i or j
- if all of the 3 above couldn't be matched, that's okay. Give me record if it has vorm = 'j'